# How can I start Steam with the window maximized?

Tags: windows-10, window, steam

When I start Steam the window is in normal state (where if I hover the window's borders with the mouse it allows me to resize it and shows the resize cursor).

The window does cover the whole screen (except the taskbar) as if it was maximized but it isn't.

Is there a way to start it in maximized state?

I have tried changing the properties of the Steam shortcut to run as maximized but it doesn't change it.

[image: Steam properties run as maximized]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam does not honor the Maximized parameter and has no Settings for full-screen.

However, Steam should remember your previous window size:

- Start Steam
- Double-click the Steam window title to make it full-screen
- Click the "X" to close Steam
- It will now remember its window size for future invocations.

Comment: That's was my suspicion. Was hoping that someone maybe knew a solution.